# timeout on transient error: Could not connect to the server 127.0.0.1:8332

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

I finished installing Bitcoin on a raspberry pi a couple days ago and have a problem. Everything worked fine yesterday (I was able to run bitcoin-cli commands just fine) but now whenever I run "bitcoind -daemon" (It says Starting Bitcoin Core), and then run "bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo" (Or any other bitcoin-cli command), it gives me the error message in the title of this post.

I have a bitcoin.conf file that contains:

```
server=1
rpcuser=<username>
rpcpassword=<password>
```

Please help :)

Comment: Is Bitcoin Core (`bitcoind`) still running?

Comment: How would I check if it is? I'm very new to this sorry.

Comment: For example, do new log lines appear (e.g. look with `tail -f ~/.bitcoin/debug.log`) or is the process still around (e.g. look if any output appears with `ps ax | fgrep bitcoind`).

Comment: It is telling me that `/home/node/.bitcoin` disk space is too low, but I have a 2TB externally connected SSD.

Comment: Sounds like your home directory isn't on that external HD.

Comment: Should I simply mount the home directory where my ssd is mounted? (`/mnt/bitcoin`)?

Comment: That's up to you, and perhaps more a question for a sysadmin site than this one.